# MobileConnect - Opt-Out Numbers across Multiple Contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

With MobileConnect, are mobile numbers that opted-out applied to all contacts that may share that number within MobileConnect?

Example below:

**Contact 1**
Contact Key: 12345
Mobile: 123-456-7890

**Contact 2**
Contact Key: 67890
Mobile: 123-456-7890

If Contact 1 opts out, will MobileConnect automatically exclude Contact 2 from receiving any further SMS messages because that mobile number is shared? Or is strictly specific to the Contact, similar to Email Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. In MobileConnect the mobile numbers stand for an 'entry', meaning the behavior is a bit different from Email Studio:

1. If `Contact A` with phone number `123` opts-out from a `keyword X`, then this number is always going to be read as opt-out for this keyword, unless it's opted back in at some point of time. 
   Meaning, `Contact B` who also has this number for this keyword, is *also* opted out. `Contact C` who is imported to Mobile Connect in the future, with this number/keyword combo - is also going to have this number as opted-out if it's still in opted-out status for some existing Contact.
2. If phone number 123 exists on `Contact A` and you now import in a `Contact B` with the same number, then `Contact A` is going to have it under `Priority 2`, meaning when `Contact A` exists in your target group (but `Contact B` *isn't*) then your SMS will **not** be sent to this 123 number.

Comment: It's all a bit tricky, but I think I understand. I really don't think it's possible to have a perfect MobileConnect database with all the possible scenarios that may come up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Priority does not work like this - Priority operates *within* the Contact to manage multiple numbers on the contact (NOT between different contacts). So, in case the contact uses multiple mobile numbers, the value of the Priority field establishes the order in which to use those mobile numbers. Therefore, two different contacts can have the same phone number, and both have Priority 1.

Comment: @charliefay - 5 years ago it was a different case. Priority 1 for a specific phone number could be only on 1 single Contact in entire MC instance. Some history behind this: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qQ5yvAAC/editing-mobileconnect-priority-in-the-ui-will-cause-all-mobile-numbers-to-share-the-same-priority